# SonarQube: When running the combined-ut-it-multimodule-maven-jacoco example I get 0% coverage

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing, sonarqube

For the sonar example combined-ut-it-multimodule-maven-jacoco example I run
 mvn clean install sonar:sonar 
and get the following output that shows 0% because it cannot find the classes directories that are in each of the modules' target directories:

```
[INFO] [13:44:38.630] Sensor JaCoCoSensor...
[INFO] [13:44:38.630] Project coverage is set to 0% since there is no directories with classes.
[INFO] [13:44:38.630] Sensor JaCoCoSensor done: 0 ms
[INFO] [13:44:38.829] Execute decorators...
[INFO] [13:44:43.156] Store results in database
[INFO] [13:44:43.672] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://vqsonar1.phx01.ebayads.com:80/dashboard/index/org.example.app-example:parent
[INFO] [13:44:43.776] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob
[INFO] [13:44:43.777] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.batch.IndexProjectPostJob
[INFO] [13:44:44.112] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.dbcleaner.ProjectPurgePostJob
[INFO] [13:44:44.181] -> Keep one snapshot per day between 2013-12-03 and 2013-12-30
[INFO] [13:44:44.182] -> Keep one snapshot per week between 2013-01-01 and 2013-12-03
[INFO] [13:44:44.182] -> Keep one snapshot per month between 2009-01-06 and 2013-01-01
[INFO] [13:44:44.183] -> Delete data prior to: 2009-01-06
[INFO] [13:44:44.308] -> Clean JaCoCo Examples :: app-example :: parent [id=11975]
[INFO] [13:44:44.379] <- Clean snapshot 14448
[INFO] [13:44:53.292] -> Clean JaCoCo Examples :: app-example :: app [id=11976]
[INFO] [13:44:53.354] -> Clean JaCoCo Examples :: app-example :: app-it [id=11977]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] JaCoCo Examples :: app-example :: parent .......... SUCCESS [2:32.824s]
[INFO] JaCoCo Examples :: app-example :: app ............. SUCCESS [1.596s]
[INFO] JaCoCo Examples :: app-example :: app-it .......... SUCCESS [0.422s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

The message says 0% code coverage but when I look at the web page it shows 50% test coverage and 80% overall integration test coverage.

Answer (score 0):

It looks strange, I can see that you are running mvn install as documentation mention https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/code-coverage/combined%20ut-it/combined-ut-it-multimodule-maven-jacoco